Ejecución maven cucumber
Buenas a tod@s.Estoy intentando crear un mini proyecto con cucumber. Que ejecute con maven apuntando en un archivo de xml a una clase llamado RunMainTest1 que esté configurada con cucumberOptions llamando a las carpetas de ejecución tanto feature como java.
este es mi feature: con una ruta: pruebaCucumber/src/test/features/01-Login
#language: es
@quick
Característica: Hacemos login en la pagina web con acceso incorrecto

  Escenario:Acceso incorrecto
    Dado estoy en la página principal
    Cuando validamos de forma incorrecta
    Entonces notifica un mensaje de acceso incorrecto 

En el archivo java donde está las expresiones o datos es aquí: pruebaCucumber/src/test/java/feature
public class Login {

    @Dado("^estoy en la página principal$")
    @Given("^I am on homepage$")
    public void estoy_en_la_página_principal() {
        System.out.println("GIVEN");

    }
    @Cuando("^validamos de forma incorrecta$")
    @When("^we validate incorrectly$")
    public void validamos_de_forma_incorrecta() {
        System.out.println("WHEN");
    }
    @Entonces("^notifica un mensaje de acceso incorrecto$")
    @Then("^reports a bad access message$")
    public void notifica_un_mensaje_de_acceso_incorrecto() {
        System.out.println("THEN");
    }
}

Si ejecuto con feature, si me funciona correctamente. Ahora cuando llamo creando el RunMainTest1 con apuntando el xml no me ejecuta nada:
xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Cucumber Suite">
    <test name="Cucumber Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="runMainTest.RunMainTestJob1"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>

java-cucumberOptions
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/features/01-Login", // Ruta de las características
        glue = "src/test/java/feature", // Ruta del paquete 
        plugin = {"pretty","summary","html:target/cucumber-reports.html"},// Plugins de reportes
        snippets = CAMELCASE
)
public class RunMainTestJob1 {
}

Si creo un beforeSuite con "sout" si me aparece esa clase, eso significa que la ruta del xml y del java es correcta, creo que el problema lo tengo en el cucumberOptions. Me podéis ayudar?
Gracias!

Tienes snippets = CAMELCASE pero tus métodos están en UNDERSCORE. Probaste sin esa línea de snippets = CAMELCASE? La verdad es que con cucumber apenas hice más que dos ejercicios básicos para ver cómo funcionaba y nada más, pero me extraña un poco esa configuración

Esa opción no afecta, lo he cambiado varias veces y no sigo que ejecute, puede ser que sea por el Intelij?

Solucionado:
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/features/01-Login", // Ruta de las características
        glue = "feature"// Ruta del paquete
)
public class RunMainTestJob1 {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;


    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickle, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickle.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}

tenia que añadir del plugin de testng y PickleWrapper
